# Importing CSV & Excel files into Visual Studio Code (Using SQLite)

Tags: sqlite, csv, visual-studio-code

New SQL learner and Visual Studio Code learner as well. Coming from a Power BI/Tableau background. Trying to learn SQLite but much of my data sources simply consist of csv and/or Excel files.

What is the easiest way to import these types of files into Visual Studio and perform some basic analysis on them? Is it suggested to create my own local SQL Server and upload these CSV/Excel files here then pul into VS or simply import them with commands?

I am coming from a BI background so I am used to creating automated pipelines that pull these types of files easily from a folder to perform transformation steps then visualize them. Is this something that can be done as well with sql/python and VS?

Bit of a beginner here and learning as I go so any type of insights is greatly appreciated.

Tried importing a table but not sure how to write which excel tab or excel file to import, then change the data types of these columns.

Comment: Are you trying to import to VS code or Visual studio ?

Comment: how is SQL Server going to help you with SQLite? Also, please be consistent with your terminology. Visual Studio is not the same thing as VS Code.